# DDR52 mode switching with device tree

Tags: linux, arm, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am trying to switch to DDR52 mode using the device tree for eMMC.
I am using arasan,sdhci-5.1 controller and linux kernel 5.2.

I have tried switching to other modes such as HS200(mmc-hs200-1_8v) and HS400(mmc-hs400-1_8v) using device-tree properties and this is working fine. However, there is not much info on how to switch to DDR52 mode in the device tree binding nodes.

Reference:
[1]https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mmc/arasan%2Csdhci.txt
[2]https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mmc/mmc.txt

```
    mmc@11000000 {
        compatible = "arasan,sdhci-5.1";
        status = "okay";
        interrupts = <0x0 0x11 0x4>;
        reg = <0x0 0x11000000 0x0 0x100>;
        clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
        clocks = <&cru SCLK_EMMC>, <&cru ACLK_EMMC>;
        phys = <0x7>;
        phy-names = "phy_arasan";
        assigned-clocks = <&cru SCLK_EMMC>;
        clock-output-names = "emmc_cardclock";
        supports-cqe;
        arasan,soc-ctl-syscon = <&grf>;
    };
```

The eMMC is detected accordingly for HS200 and HS400. But will need info on how to configure to DDR52 in the device-tree.

Comment: I think this is negotiated with the cards.  The DDR52 uses the [`mmc_hs400_to_hs200()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c?h=v5.3-rc7#n1232), so if you select hs200 it seem like it would work with a DDR52 card.  The host controller should support a variety of cards, so it depends what is inserted if you support card detect and it is not direct soldered... or that is my naive guess.